# How To Use Url Rewrite With PHP on CGI

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, fastcgi, url-rewrite-module

I am familier with mod_rewrite that i use with apache for url rewrite with my php website . But my php is running on cgi . How Can i Use Url Rewrite in .htaccess with php on cgi

I am Using Linux VPS from 1and1 with php on CGI
I am using following code to remove .php from url's

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

But It says the following Not Found Error now

## Its for About.php

```
The document name you requested (/About) could not be found on this server.
```

Comment: What web server are you using? Nginx? Depending on the web server, you will probably need to look up how you create rewrites for that specific server. Most can't read htaccess files. (as far as I know, those are Apache-only).

Comment: I am using Linux VPS from 1and1

Comment: That doesn't help me. No idea what those VPS's are using.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Can you please tell me what other info you need

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am adding some more info to my question that may help you

Comment: I need what I asked... what web server? If you are using a hosting solution that doesn't run Apache, or if they do and .htaccess doesn't work, I would contact them and ask for a solution. Surly they would be able to help you.

Comment: One thing to confirm is .htaccess works on one of the other vps servers that contains website built with codeigniter and url rewrite is running fine with routes.php

Comment: the other one is having same package on 1and1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mistake was I forget to mention

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
```

**Correct Code Is below**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]



# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```